# php file uploading type restrictions

Tags: php, file-upload, size

I have a problem with file extensions in php.

```
if ($_FILES['file']['type'] != 'image/png' || 'image/jpg') {
                   echo "wrong type";
                   exit;
     }
```

this doesn't allow any type of file to upload

```
if ($_FILES['file']['type'] != ('image/png' || 'image/jpg')) {
                   echo "wrong type";
                   exit;
     }
```

this allows any type of file to upload.

Whats the matter?

Comment: What's the difference?

Comment: Boolean logic != english grammar. Compare your variable explicitly, twice: `$_FILES['file']['type'] != 'image/png' || $_FILES['file']['type'] != 'image/jpg'`

Comment: look at the brackers at the 1 example there is: if (code)
at the second there is if(code(code)), i basically want to allow only jpg and png file to upload

Answer (score 0):

Your conditional statement is incorrect. It should look like this:

```
if (($_FILES['file']['type'] != 'image/png') || 
       ($_FILES['file']['type'] != 'image/jpg')) {
                   echo "wrong type";
                   exit;
     }
```

Your first snipped always resolves to true because of `|| 'image/jpg'` is always true.

The second snippet resolves `('image/png' || 'image/jpg')` to true everytime, which DOES NOT equal `$_FILES['file']['type']`

Comment: it doesn't work, when I upload jpg file it shows "wrong type";

Comment: the logic is correct, verify what is stored in your `$_FILES` variable. Maybe you need to also check for JPEG as well as JPG?

Comment: did you verify that `$_FILES['file']['type']` actually contains 'image/jpg'? Your upload could be failing for another reason, making it seem like its the wrong file type....

Comment: im new in PHP, I don't know exactly how to verify this, but all images I upload are jpg/png/gif(wanted to see if it worked correctly). For some time it did to be honest and I don't know what happened really.

Comment: Add an `echo $_FILES['file']['type']` before the `if` condition to make sure that the variable is actually holding `'image/jpg'` because if your upload failed for some reason, that variable would be empty in turn causing your code to think its the wrong type, when really its non existent....